# share social text and link react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I add function button to share text + link on social media

[image: share]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share text to other apps, you would have to use navigator.share

For more information, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-web-share-api-for-native-share-options-in-html-javascript/